# Computability of a halting oracle for a specific class of machines

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Let us consider the set of machines/algorithms with constant inputs (I would have preferred to say **no inputs** but I was told that every algorithm/machine has to have an input). We call $\mathcal{M}$ the set of all machines and define $C \in \mathcal{M}$ as follows:
$$ C(I) = \begin{cases} LOOP, \hspace{0.5cm} I \neq C\\ HALT, \hspace{0.5cm} I = C \end{cases}$$
We next define the following class of machines:
$$ \mathcal{M}_0 = \{ M \in \mathcal{M}| M(I) \text{   halts if } I \neq C \}$$
Please note that $C \not\in \mathcal{M}_0$.

Let us now search for a halting oracle $H: \mathcal{M}_0 \times \{ inputs\} \to \{ Yes, No\}$ defined as follows:

$$ H(M_0,I) = \begin{cases} Yes, \hspace{0.5cm} \text{if } M_0(I) \text{ halts }\\ No, \hspace{0.5cm} \text{if } M_0(I) \text{ does not halt} \end{cases}$$

Next we find impossible to apply the Turing's argument for such a machine. Indeed let's consider the machine $N$ with inputs in $\{Yes,No\}$ defined like so: $N(Yes)$ loops for ever and $N(No)$ halts. Then construct the function $$X(I) = N(H(I,I))$$ for all $I \in \mathcal{M}_0$. Assuming that $X \in \mathcal{M}_0$ one evaluates $$X(X) = N(H(X,X))$$ but

1. if $X \neq C$ follows that $X(X)$ halts hence $X(X) = N(Yes)$ which loops $\to$ contradiction
2. if $X = C$ follows that $X \not\in \mathcal{M}_0$ $\to$ contradiction

It follows that $X \not\in \mathcal{M}_0$ ... and we cannot apply $X$ to itself!

### Question:

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: Your definition of $M_0$ seems to be cyclic. Is there a typo there?

Comment: There is no typo ... just wanted to say that "the user" can replace $M_0(C)$ with the unique "thing" that $M_0$ is supposed to do ... That was the best way I found to express that ... I am just trying somehow to say that the machines in $\mathcal{M}_0$ do not have inputs, or do not depend on the inputs

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot follow your argument at all. It's not clear to me what you're trying to show, nor what the steps are. Perhaps add some more explanations as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have made an edit! Is it clearer now?

Comment: I am just trying to define a subset of machines for which the proof used by Turing does not work. I hope therefore to find a class of useful machines for which exists a computable halting oracle ...

Comment: Not really, sorry. Are you claiming that the set of machines that don't take inputs have a decidable halting problem? Because that's not true. You can easily reduce the halting problem for Turing machines to the halting problem of Turing machines that do not take an input.

Comment: Uhmm ... I am not claiming that, I just defined a set of machines, $\mathcal{M}_0$, for which the proof of the classical Halting problem doesn't seem to apply. I was asking for correctness check

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W Well, this was just a short endeavor in this field (where fairly all my experience is from these questions + superficial videos). I will correct that in the future!